# Automatically add vertical space /only/ between two sequential paragraphs

Tags: spacing, sectioning, paragraphs, parskip

I am using KOMA-script scrreprt class.

I know I can use `\usepackage{parskip}` or `\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}`, but both of these also affect headings.

Adding `\vspace{12pt}` manually between all two sequential paragraphs seems to work, but that's anything but convenient. Is there a way to automate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a KOMA-Script class, the solution is already provided by the class itself:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
```

(page 49 in the English documentation).

You can also add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace{-1\parskip}}
```

if you don't want a `\parskip` added immediately after a chapter title.

For section titles use **titlesec**. For customizing the amount of the `\parskip`, use something like

```
\setparsizes{\parindent}{50pt plus 20pt minus 30pt}{\parfillskip}
```

in your preamble (adjusting the ridiculous values I put just as an example). It's important to provide stretching and shrinking components to help text fit in the page.

Comment: But this solution too adds vertical space after chapter headings.

Comment: You can't add _more_ spacing between paragraphs by this method, however.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, by using `\setparsizes{\parindent}{50pt}{\parfillskip}`; the first argument sets the parindent, the second the parskip and the third the parfillskip. Passing the parameters themselves will not change them.

Comment: @egreg aha. That looks like it might be closer to solving Andres' problem, I think you should add that to your answer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, here is what I ended with: http://pastebin.com/Gizvvszc It actually adds about 1mm to list spacing and removes some millimeters from section and lower level headings' spacing compared to using scrreprt without setting parskip, but as this is customizable it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the best way would be to use `parskip` (KOMA has its own way of affecting paragraph skips I think) and then changing the heading spacing to compensate. Here's an example to show how you might do it with the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{parskip,lipsum,titlesec}
\setlength{\parskip}{50pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{-40pt}{-40pt}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Second}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

(I've exaggerated the parskip so it's easier to see what's going on.) You may want to add stretch glues to the `beforeskip` and `afterskip` arguments of `\titlespacing`.

Comment: Lists also use paragraph spacing this way. Section titles are okay and this approach can also be used for subsection and etc, but what about chapters?

Comment: You have to use `\parskip=0pt` in the code for chapter make up.

Comment: @Andres I've not had time to test this properly. What goes wrong with chapters? Does egreg's comment help?

Comment: Chapter headings appearently use \parskip value and ignoe \titlespacing.

Comment: @Andres `titlesec` can do `\titlespacing*{\chapter}...` try that?

Comment: @egreg, @Seamus, the following code still produces big vertical spaces after chapter headings:
`\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{parskip,lipsum,titlesec}
\setlength{\parskip}{50pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{-40pt}
\begin{document}
\parskip=0pt
\chapter{First}
\parskip=50pt
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}`

Comment: @Andres I do not know how to fix that. Sorry.